# ng-repeat wont iterate over nested JSON arrays

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a problem. I can't get ng-repeat to show any data in my html side.

It's a $http.get to a JSON obejct with nested arrays.
HTML:

```
<head>
<script data-require="angular.js@1.3.15" data-semver="1.3.15"src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.15/angular.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
<script src="script.js"></script>

</head>


<body ng-app="stdViewer" ng-controller="stdCtrl">
<h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>



 <div ng-repeat="IKAS_standarder in data">

 {{IKAS_standarder.version}}



 <div ng-repeat="standarder in IKAS_standarder">


  {{standarder.tema}}



   <b>Jobs:</b><br/> 

   </div>
   </div>

   </body>






    </html>
```

Script

```
  (function() {
 var stdCtrl = function($scope, $http) {

var onSucces = function(response) {
  $scope.data = response.data;
};

var onError = function(reason) {
  $scope.error = reason;
};

$http.get("http://46.31.18.93/DataService/IKAS_standard/Sygehuse?  format=json").then(onSucces, onError);
$scope.data = '';
$scope.repoSortOrder = "-SektorID";

};
var app = angular.module("stdViewer", []);
app.controller("stdCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", stdCtrl]);

 }());
```

I have a pluncker set up here :http://plnkr.co/edit/ERRR8Sj5eG6P4DpRuJx3?p=preview

Comment: I dont see any data coming in.

Comment: The data is in - try {{IKAS_standarder}} then is wil be shown

Comment: Demo is no good with a cross domain request that fails

Comment: @charlietfl what do you mean? I am new to Pluncker

Comment: WHat I meant was before you changed the url on the request , the original request was not working due to CORS...so we couldn't even see any data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your ng-repeats to:

```
<div ng-repeat="IKAS_standarder in data.IKAS_standarder">...</div>
```

and

```
<div ng-repeat="standarder in IKAS_standarder.standarder">...</div>
```

For the first one you could als change the onSuccess method to

```
$scope.data = response.data.IKAS_standarder
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div ng-repeat="IKAS_standarder in data">
   <div ng-repeat="std in IKAS_standarder">
     <div ng-repeat="istandarder in std.standarder">
        {{istandarder}}
        <br/>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Try this